# Specific term for "snowflake" or "fingerprint"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

Is there a specific term for something like a fingerprint or snowflake that exists in many instances but every instance is unique? or is that just called "unique"...

Comment: I would just say "unique" or "individual", but there are probably other terms, which describe this characteristic.

Comment: Examples of a concept is often called "an instance" or "an instantiation"

Answer (score 0):

The word "**distict**" establishes the quality of being intrinsically unique among many.

> Each snowflake or fingerprint is **distinct** in its form.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/distinct

There are also words like "**irreplicable**", "**irreproducible**", or "**unreproducible**" that suggest that something cannot be reproduced or copied. Each one produced is therefore unique.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/irreproducible

Answer (score -2):

My main comment is to not modify "unique," "round," "correct," "true," etc.  Something either is or it isn't.

Comment: A most unique answer

Comment: I've seen more unique answers.